# Understanding firefox extension code

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firefox-addon, add-on

I am going through a Firefox extension code. But I am not able to understand how extension code works. Where does it start its execution?
Is there a starting point like `main()` in C?

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple situations for an addon to start.

From the top of my head i can remember the following:

- Toolbar button - The extension only does something when you click it, so you could say that the starting point is the function that the button calls.
- Context Menu - Same as the , but for context menu item
- Event triggered start - The extension may be listening to page load / unload, (etc) events and start from there. In this case look for `window.addEventListener(...)`